# microsoft outlook macro to move incoming emails from inbox to a particular folder

Tags: vba, outlook

May I know what code should I put in the macro to be able immediately transfer the files from my inbox to another particular folder after I've seen it come in my inbox?  I do not wish to automatically forward it to another folder, I want it happen once I've pressed a particular combination of keys.  Help please?  Am not well-adept with Visual Basic?

Comment: I agree with the votes to close because this is not (actually) a programming question. I hope the answer below solves your problem -- the ready-to-go solution in Outlook works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro to do this, it can be accomplished with rules.

I'm assuming Outlook 2013, but this will basically apply to most versions:

1. Go to Inbox > Rules > Create Rule > Advanced Options
2. Checkmark 'Where my name is in the To box' (or any other option you choose)
3. Click Next
4. Checkmark 'move it to a specified folder', and then click the blue url on the name 'specified folder', and choose the folder
5. Click Next
6. Choose any other rules you want, and click Next
7. Verify your rule setup, and click Finish

Answer (score 0):

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx

```
Sub MoveMessageToTestFolder()

' Works on one selected item

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Add As many  .Folders("SubfolderName")  as needed
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Test")
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    If TypeOf myItem Is mailitem Then
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
    End If

    Set myNameSpace = Nothing
    Set myInbox = Nothing
    Set myDestFolder = Nothing
    Set myItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm